# Conditional expectation of Poisson, conditional on Poisson sums

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, conditional-expectation, joint-distribution, combinatorics

Consider independent Poisson random variables $X_1\sim \text{Poisson}(\alpha_1)$, $X_2\sim \text{Poisson}(\alpha_2)$, $Y\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, and suppose $Z_1=X_1+Y$ and $Z_2=X_2+Y$. I want to find the conditional expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y|Z_1 = z_1,Z_2=z_2).
$$
It is not difficult to see that
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y|Z_1 = z_1,Z_2=z_2) = \dfrac{
\sum\limits_{y=0}^{min(z_1,z_2)} y P(Y=y,Z_1 = z_1,Z_2=z_2)
}{
\sum\limits_{y=0}^{min(z_1,z_2)}  P(Y=y,Z_1 = z_1,Z_2=z_2)
},
$$
where the joint PMF for $y=0,1,\dots, min(z_1,z_2)$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(Y=y,Z_1 = z_1,Z_2=z_2) &=
P(Z_1 = z_1,Z_2=z_2|Y=y)P(Y=y)
\\& =
P(X_1 = z_1-y)P(X_2 = z_2-y)P(Y=y)
\\& =
e^{-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\lambda)}\left[\dfrac{\alpha_1^{z_1-y}}{(z_1-y)!}\right]
\left[\dfrac{\alpha_2^{z_2-y}}{(z_2-y)!}\right]
\left[\dfrac{\lambda^{y}}{y!}\right].
\end{split}
\end{equation}
However, to use this joint PMF we need to solve sums of this form:
$$
\sum\limits_{y=0}^{min(z_1,z_2)}
\left[\dfrac{\alpha_1^{z_1-y}}{(z_1-y)!}\right]
\left[\dfrac{\alpha_2^{z_2-y}}{(z_2-y)!}\right]
\left[\dfrac{\lambda^{y}}{y!}\right].
$$
If the first term inside the sum was not there, this would turn into the binomial formula. In fact, we know that $Y|(Z_1=z_1)$ and $Y|(Z_2=z_2)$  are both binomial random variables. However, characterizing the random variable $Y|(Z_1=z_1,Z_2=z_2)$ requires solving sums as the one described above. Thoughts?

Comment: It's a confluent hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably $X_1,X_2,Y$ are independent and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\lambda$ are known.

You may not be able to do much better than calculating the sum but it is not difficult, as shown in the examples below.

$Y$ does not seem to have a conditional binomial distribution when $\min(z_1,z_2) > 1$.

Empirically to my surprise, swapping $z_1$ and $z_2$ but keeping $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\lambda$ unchanged does not affect the conditional distribution or conditional expectation of $Y$.  Meanwhile, unlike conditioning on just one of $Z_1$ or $Z_2$, doubling everything here does not double the conditional expectation of $Y$, again slightly surprising.  Here is an illustration in R:

```
pmfY <- function(alpha1, alpha2, lambda, z1, z2){
   possY <- 0:min(z1, z2)
   likeY <- dpois(possY, lambda) * 
              dpois(z1 - possY, alpha1) * dpois(z2 - possY, alpha2)  
   return(likeY / sum(likeY))
   }

EY <- function(alpha1, alpha2, lambda, z1, z2){
   return(sum(0:min(z1, z2) * pmfY(alpha1, alpha2, lambda, z1, z2)))
   }
```

with the examples

```
EY(alpha1=1, alpha2=4, lambda=3, z1=4,  z2=7)
# 3.100817
EY(alpha1=1, alpha2=4, lambda=3, z1=7,  z2=4)
# 3.100817
EY(alpha1=2, alpha2=8, lambda=6, z1=14, z2=8)
# 6.100545
```